# Same string not equal when compare

Tags: c#, string, compare, equals

I have 2 identical strings, one from SQL Server, another saved in `app.config`.
When I compare the two, they are not equal. So I convert these strings to char array, and it have different in int value.

Anyone know why?

Sorry for my English.

Thanks for reading!

[image]

Comment: One is Unicode and the other is using encoding.  Notice the character at index 1.  It is the same character with different code.  an encoded character is < 256.   So x has 208 which is 8 bit encoded and y has 272 that is not encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, it happened because I have a mistake in when declare SQL Server data type. It should be nvarchar but I have declared it varchar.

Thank you for all your support!

[image: Solve]

Answer (score 3):

Ð (208) is a capital letter of [Eth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth). Đ (272) is a capital letter of [D with stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_with_stroke).

Two letters have same visual but they aren't same.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that you have mixed *encoding*; you can try to encode (**guess**: I think you have Win-1250 encoding) the first string (which is `x`) in a right way (quick patch):

```
string source = "KÐB";

Console.Write($"Before: {source} :: {string.Join(" ", source.Select(c => (int)c))}"); 

string target = Encoding
  .GetEncoding(1250)
  .GetString(source.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray());

Console.Write($"After: {target} :: {string.Join(" ", target.Select(c => (int)c))}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
Before: KÐB :: 75 208 66
After: KĐB :: 75 272 66
```

**Usage:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static string MyEncodingPatch(string value) => value == null 
  ? null 
  : Encoding.GetEncoding(1250).GetString(value.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray());

...

if (string.Equals(MyEncodingPatch(x), y)) {
  ...
}
```

Note: if `x` has its origin in a *file*, specify its encoding:

```
string x = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\MyData.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
```